# JQuery Selector Shortcuts

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Given the following code:

```
$(div.now span).text('now');
$(div.30days span).text('30days');
$(div.60days span).text('60days');
```

If I want to shorten things up, this seems like the logical thing to do as in:

```
$('span', 'div.now, div.30days, div.60days').text(some text);
```

Now, in the shortened version, I want to set the text to that of the class name but cant seem to figure out how to do it. Any ideas? I realize this is not an ideal thing to do but just an experiment in JQuery if you will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$("div span").each(function(){
  $(this).text($(this).closest('div').attr('class'))
})​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mmDQV/)

Comment: This is pretty good.I actually did a version of this but was thinking it could be shorter. I like this. I didnt think about the closest. Very cool. THanks so much.

Comment: @DavidWhitten just be careful about nested divs. If you have `<div class="now"><div><span/></div></div>` the `closest` call will select the innermost div. You could use the same selector you used for the context (in your original example) as argument for `closest` to avoid that. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11805742/520779) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function instead of a string in the `text` argument:

```
$('span', 'div.now, div.30days, div.60days').text(function() {
    return $(this).closest('div.now, div.30days, div.60days').attr("class");
});
```

Calling it that way, `this` is bound to the current element (a `span`), so you only need to retrieve its <strike>parent's</strike> closest ancestor div's class and return it.

Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypAyA/). Note that it works even if there are nested divs (since it uses the same selector for `closest` as it used for the original context).

Answer (score 0):

this is what you want?

```
$('div.now', 'div.30days', 'div.60days').each(function(){
  $(this).text(this.className); 
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to loop using `each`.

The best way to do it is the following.

```
$('div span').text(function() {
    return this.parentNode.className;
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/By8NA/1/)